# C# Mock Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a unit test which logs onto a database and checks the username and password, but I need to recreate these test now using mocks.

I have been searching online but cannot find anything like what I am trying to achieve. Below is the original test

```
[TestMethod()]
public void LoginTest()
{
    this.errorText = string.Empty;
    this.user = MasterDataManager.GetInstance().Login("JohnSmith", "123", out errorText);
    Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, errorText);
}
```

I have written a test from what I have found online, it passes but I don't really know why to be honest. I have used Rhino Mocks here but am open to any help or solutions to get me going

```
[TestMethod()]
public void LoginTestMock()
{
    var repo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IAbstractConnector>();
    repo.Login("JohnSmith", "123", out errorText);
    repo.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Comment: What do you think "VerifyAllExpectations" is going to check? What do you think "Passing unit test" actually means in this context?

Comment: what do you want to test?

Comment: I am trying to mock a test that returns an empty string

Comment: Your test only uses a mock, that doesn't really have much point.  It looks to me that you should still be calling the same method as you originally were but passing a mock into the class under test so it doesn't actually access the database.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your "...it passes but I don't really know why to be honest.": It passes, because you have *not* set any expectations, hence nothing to verify.
Check,e.g.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/How_to_Use_Rhino_Mocks/Introduction